# How to serve my Shopify store on every route except /products/:id which would load a totally different app?

Tags: nginx, shopify

I have two different apps. One is a Shopify app (my-stor.shopify.com) and the other is a Next.js app. I'd like to have a custom domain that serves my Shopify store in basically every route except the `my-custom-domain.com/products/:id` which I'd like to load my Next.js app.

My custom domain is on Amazon EC2 and I set up Nginx as a web server over there.

My first question is: Is that possible to have a Nginx congif that handles these two different apps based on the URL structure?

My second question is: If that is possible, how can I do it (in Nginx)?

I tried something like this but with no success:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ^~ /products/ {
        proxy_pass https://my-store.myshopify.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```